# How to get the absolute device orientation on Firefox for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox

I need to implement a compass for my webpage.
There are a lot of resources on how to accomplish this for Chrome and Safari but I can't find a way to do this on Firefox. So this is my current approach:

```
let orientation;
if (Safari_iOS) {
  //request permission, then:
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event) {
    orientation = event.webkitCompassHeading;
  }, true);
} else if (Chrome_Android) {
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", function(event) {
    orientation = event.alpha;
  }, true);
} else {//Firefox
//What now?
}
```

So how do I do it for Firefox?

Comment: I think that the deviceorientation listener should work in Firefox according to Mozilla's docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Detecting_device_orientation

Comment: @JohnDoe Yeah, but as far as I know Firefox does not support the webkitCompassHeading attribute and therefore I can't get the absolute orientation